# Determine who requested action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So, I have two action methods A=`public ActionResult PlaceOrder(PlaceOrderVM model)` and  B=`public ActionResult IngredientsDeficiency()`. And I want to know IN B if B was a result of redirection from A. Or in general redirection. I just want to prevent users from requesting method B by themselves. But they can see View if it was redirect from server. Hope someone will understand...

---

Works

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult PlaceOrder(PlaceOrderVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var cosumed = _pizzaRepository.TryConsumeIngredients(model.PizzaId);
            if (cosumed == false)
            {
                return View("IngredientsDeficiency");
            }

            _pizzaRepository.InsertOrder(model);
            _pizzaRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Orders", "User");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Doesn't work

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult PlaceOrder(PlaceOrderVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var cosumed = _pizzaRepository.TryConsumeIngredients(model.PizzaId);
            if (cosumed == false)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("IngredientsDeficiency");
            }

            _pizzaRepository.InsertOrder(model);
            _pizzaRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Orders", "User");
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult IngredientsDeficiency()
    {
        return View("IngredientsDeficiency");
    }
```

Error: `The action 'IngredientsDeficiency' is accessible only by a child request.`

Comment: Couldn't you just make B private and use standard control flow to send users to it?

Comment: Yea, works. I am like a blind horse, new view = new action method. You can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to set a Session variable flag in the `public ActionResult PlaceOrder(PlaceOrderVM model)` and check that flag in the `public ActionResult IngredientsDeficiency()`. Also you can use the TempData collection and the data will be stored only for the next request and you would not have to worry about removing it.

If you don't want to use session, you can also change your `public ActionResult PlaceOrder(PlaceOrderVM model)` to return the result view of `IngredientsDeficiency` directly.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of [ChildActionOnlyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) action attribute.

See [example here](http://dotnethelpers.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/child-action-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4/)

Comment: Child action is something that you can invoke from the view itself. OP wants to know where the user was redirected from.

Comment: ChildActionOnly attribute restricts that action be called from another action not directly accessed..

Comment: this will not be usable in this scenario according to you??

Comment: You would only be able to access the child method via the parent. You cant access it directly. You will get the following error The action (action) is accessible only by a child request.

Comment: If you can explain how it solves the question in the post would be great.

Comment: OP wants to restrict that the action not be called directly, it is for that purpose.

Comment: OP still wants to be able to go IngredientsDeficiency action directly.

Comment: up for ChildActionOnly. an action marked by ChildActionOnly prevent action to be called as a result of user request. Rather than change the work flow, this one is more decent to solve the problem.

Comment: I paste some code, coz I feel like I aint said sth important.

Comment: you want to be action called directly without redirect from application?

Comment: Like I said: "But they can see View `if it was` redirect from server."